# Ubuntu 18.04 GUI is not working after installing cuda 10.0 in virtual ubuntu machine using vmware on windows 10 host machine

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox, vmware

I have windows 10 host machine with NVIDIA Quadro  M1000 GPU. In this host machine, I have VMware workstation Pro 15.5 installed for virtual Linux machines. In vmware I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. In Ubuntu I have installed Cuda 10.0 followed the instruction given by [nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive%20target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804).

After installation, I have rebooted the system and I was able to log into the system. It was showing a warning that display configuration is not set and after that screen completely freezes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the next suggestion:

You need to switch to tty3 somehow (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> - 
I don't remember how to do it in vmware) and try to switch to a different display manager:

```
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
sudo systemctl enable gdm3
sudo systemctl start gdm3
```

The same could be executed for lightdm, lxdm, kdm, ssdm, xdm.

To switch to tty, [try](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1011705):

- Press Ctrl+Alt+Spacebar.
- Keep holding Ctrl+Alt but release the space bar.
- Press the desired key (for example F3).